# Stuck on a Query for a stock trading spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I am currently trying to create a simple but effective spreadsheet to track stock trading, but I am coming across some barriers. I created a sheet called 'movimentacoes' to basically input in and out (compra e venda), in Portuguese. With that, I want to track every transaction I made, how much I paid, date, ticker, etc etc. That is the easy part. Via some help here already (from an amazing guy named Bryan), I was able to do most of these queries, but now I am partially stuck on the last query I need.

I need to get an average of all 'buy' instances of a ticker (quantity X price paid) from ‘Movimentacoes’ that matches the queried list of 'sold' ones in tab ‘Vendas’. I created the beginning of the query and the last part, being stuck only on this average with 2 conditionals. I am attaching an screenshot below as well as a link to the spreadsheet itself to make it easier for whoever is able to help understand better the case.

[image]

Spreadsheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_qGSWwN5DmKCh8E5hwNFT6xKqpHmQEHTVkpaFvXD_J0/edit?usp=sharing

Codes used so far:

1st part query:

> =QUERY('Movimentações'!A:N,"select F, C, D, E WHERE A is not null AND A = 'Venda' AND D != 'Renda Fixa'",0)

2nd part query (broken and dont know how to do the averages with conditionals)

> =QUERY('Movimentações'!A:N, "SELECT (I-1*J) WHERE A = 'Compra'")

3rd part query:

> =QUERY('Movimentações'!A:M,"select M WHERE A='Venda' AND D != 'Renda Fixa'",0)

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: To hide first row of query function output use offset clause like `offset 1`. Which one is you desired result? I don't see anywhere you input `Buy` in your sheet.

Comment: Can you show us your query?

Comment: Edited: Queries provided now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal goes like this:

```js
=QUERY(QUERY({QUERY('Movimentações'!A2:J,"Select F,C,D,E,(I*-1),(I*-1*J),(I*0),(J*0) where A matches 'Venda' label (I*-1) '', (I*-1*J) ''",0);QUERY('Movimentações'!A2:J,"Select F,C,D,E,(I*0),(J*0),I,(I*J) where A matches 'Compra'",0)},"Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, sum(Col5),sum(Col6),sum(Col7),sum(Col8),sum(Col5)+sum(Col7) where Col1 is not null group by Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4",0),"Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col8, (Col6*-1) where Col1 is not null and Col5 < 0 label (Col6*-1) ''",0)
```

#### Result:

[image]

You will just need to add the `Total` column that you already have next to it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. This is working, however it only considers a 'venda' (sell) if I sell all the stocks at one. Say, for example, I have sold 15 shares of 'HGBS11', it won't appear there. But if I set the sale to 17 (the total I have), then it appears in the list. I am trying to have a look at the formula right now to see if I catch something.

Comment: @Xamineh Updated the answer. Let me know if that works for you now!

Comment: Thank you very much. That works now. Would you be able to help me with something else? I just noticed the column 'Validade' from 'Renda Fixa Tab' is querying a wrong value. It's giving me the date I bought the stock instead of the day it expires. Column B instead of column G from 'Movimentacoes Tab'.

Comment: @Xamineh I think I have the solution already but because of the community rules it would be better to create another post since it is something different from the original question in this post. You can create a different question and provide me the link and I'll try to answer there if you like.

Comment: I see. A new post has been created here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75900402/fixing-a-query-formula-in-gsheets

Comment: @Xamineh left an answer in the new post