# Fixing a query formula in Gsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am currently trying to create a simple but effective spreadsheet to track stock trading, but I am coming across some barriers. I created a sheet called 'movimentacoes' to basically input in and out (compra e venda), in Portuguese. With that, I want to track every transaction I made, how much I paid, date, ticker, etc etc.
In one of my tabs, I just noticed the column 'Validade' from 'Renda Fixa Tab' is querying a wrong value. It's giving me the date I bought the stock instead of the day it expires. Column B instead of column G from 'Movimentacoes Tab'.
[image]

Spreadsheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_qGSWwN5DmKCh8E5hwNFT6xKqpHmQEHTVkpaFvXD_J0/edit#gid=1689387102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following query:

```js
=QUERY(QUERY(FILTER('Movimentações'!A:K,'Movimentações'!G:G),"Select Col3,Col4,Col5,Col7,datediff(Col7,Col2)/365,Col8,Col9*Col10,datediff(now(),Col2) where Col4 matches 'Renda Fixa' label datediff(Col7,Col2)/365 '', Col9*Col10 '', datediff(now(),Col2) '' format datediff(Col7,Col2)/365 '0'"),"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4")
```